# How to flattens empty directories with hidden files in eclipse explorer

Tags: eclipse, explorer, hierarchical, representation

I have a project folder like below. And every sub-folder have a .svn hidden folder/file. These folders/files causes the hierarchical representation can NOT flattens empty directories. Yes, it is not EMPTY actually. Can any body help ?

```
-com
  -company
    -server
      -core
        -web
```

[Windows 64][Eclipse Kepler][Package Explorer/Project Explorer]

Thanks

Comment: Do you SVN installed in Eclipse? The SVN code should arrange that the .svn folders are ignored.

Comment: Thank you greg. It works after installed the subclipse plug-in.